# Spring 3.0 MVC Controller Request Mappings

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have 2 controllers in my app as follows

```
@Controller("/test1")
public class Test1Controller {
    @RequestMapping("/new")
    public String newtest1() {
     //....
    }  
}

@Controller("/test2")
public class Test2Controller {
    @RequestMapping("/new")
    public String newtest2() {
     //....
    }  
}
```

Now, if I make a request to     `/test2/new`    the request is going to the other controller     `/test1/new`. Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: Both classes have the same name (`Test1Controller`) - I assume this is a mistake?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: that does not matter. cause controller beans names are diffrent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolving off the controller name is just a fallback, it won't mix-and-match between that and actual request mappings.  Just put a real request mapping on the controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test1")
public class Test1Controller {
    @RequestMapping("/new")
    public String newtest1() {
     //....
    }  
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test2")
public class Test2Controller {
    @RequestMapping("/new")
    public String newtest2() {
     //....
    }  
}
```

Comment: some reason, this is also not working for me :(. Now the request is not intercepted by the controller at all.

Comment: what is the full URL from root/what is the dispatcher servlet mapped to?  Are you using mvc:annotation-driven or did you set up your own mapping handler?

Comment: To use the type level @RequestMapping you will want to remove the conflicting bean name based mapping.  (That is, do not have both @Controller("/test") and @RequestMapping("/test")) And make sure DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping is loaded (if not using the defaults.)

Comment: Rereading your description of the original problem it sounds like you may also have the dispatcher mapped onto /test1 and /test2 inside web.xml which would cause that same kind of problem.  The dispatcher servlet should be mapped in web.xml to a level above the controllers.

Comment: I am not using any handlers. My full url path would be something like `http://localhost:8080/myca/test1/new`. I am declaring something like this `@Controller @RequestMapping("/test1") ...`

Comment: and what does the dispatcher mapping in web.xml look like?  it should be *only* /myca

Comment: Thanks Affe. I also had the url mappings in web.xml as well, because of which it was not working.